# In maven, how to name war file different in release than in snapshot build

Tags: java, maven, release

I'm using the maven-war plugin. I've also looked at the maven-versions plugin. In neither case do I see how to give a different name to a snapshot build than a release build.

I've seen examples using profiles but the docs seem to indicate that the use of profiles in the pom.xml is not a good idea.

How should this be done?

Comment: Where else would you use profiles?

Comment: Typically one would place the version number on the artifact name, thus distinguishing it.

Comment: BTW: Profiles 'only' belong in the pom.

Comment: Why would you like to change the name between being a SNAPSHOT or a release? only one things you could do to name it different in your target folder via `<finalName>...</finalName>` otherwise it does not make sense to make. Can you elaborate a little bit more what you problem is or what your purpose is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>        
          <classifier>${envClassifier}</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>snapshot</id>
      <properties>
        <envClassifier>snapshot</envClassifier>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
       <properties>
        <envClassifier>release</envClassifier>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Now, run command `mvn clean install -Psnapshot` Or `mvn clean install -Prelease` to get your desired artifacts. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can control final war file name by [`warName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warName) attribute